# How does schema inference work in spark.read.parquet?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I'm trying to read a parquet file on spark and I have a question.

How is the type inferred when loading a parquet file with spark.read.parquet?

- **1**. Parquet Type **INT32** -> Spark Type **IntegerType**
- **2**. Parquet inferred from **actual stored values** -> Spark **IntegerType**

Is there a dictionary for mapping like **1**?
Or is it inferred from the actual stored values like **2**?

Comment: Just look into specification of Parquet format: https://github.com/apache/parquet-format#metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark uses the parquet schema to parse it to an internal representation (i.e, StructType), it is a bit hard to find this information on spark docs. I went through the code to find the mapping you are looking for here:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetSchemaConverter.scala#L197-L281

Comment: To be fair, Parquet is meant to be a data storage format and not a data exchange format, which is probably why the documentation does't go into schema mapping details.

Comment: @HristoIliev you are probably right the info is too specific to be on the documentation, on the other hand details like these are quite handy. Maybe it belongs in developer docs...